# (Left) CTRL + right arrow not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am new to Linux, and just installed Ubuntu 14.04.
The (left) <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd> combination doesn't work.
for instance,

(left) <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>Left</kbd>, (skipping text) is broken

(left) <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>, (window snap) is broken

(left) <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>, (change workspace) is broken

All other arrow combination works. The above key combinations works when using 
(right) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

The keys are correctly mapped as:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep 37 


keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L


$ xmodmap -pke | grep 105

keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
```

Not sure if it is important, but I have both Swedish and English (US) input languages installed, (the keyboard is US).

Edit:
The <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd> has also stopped working, after the most recent Ubuntu update.
I reinstalled Ubuntu to check if that would fix it, it did not.

Thanks!

Comment: ` xmodmap -pke | grep 37` and ` xmodmap -pke | grep 105` it shows the same output for me as well, however my shortcut-keys are working for "skipping text" and "window snap" (I dont user workspaces) The only thing I can think of is something wrong with your left Ctrl. I would advise you to start `xev` and start pressing the keys especially the Left Ctrl see how it is recognised.   Sorry I am not a pro.

Comment: Leo, did you upgrade from a previous version? And could you please teleport me some päron cider? ;-)

Comment: I played around with `xev` but it only recognize single key strokes, not combinations. My (left) Ctrl is working it's only misbehaving when used in combination with right arrow. It is a fresh install of 14.04. No dual os or upgrades. BTW, Fabby, the päron cider is on the way!